# Cakephp : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare services_twilio_autoload()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x.. i am using twilio  for sending sms but i am getting this error

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Services_Twilio_autoload() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\Lib\twilio\Twilio.php:3)

how can i sort this issue.. 
here someone asked the same question and he even tell the solution that how he sort the problem but i didnt get it

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/97

Comment: Just read the error message. It clearly tells you what is wrong and by this the solution is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is redeclaring the autoload handler in Twilio file. Just update the file `twilio/Services/Twilio.php` and when it says:

```
spl_autoload_register('Services_Twilio_autoload');
```

change it by

```
spl_autoload_register('Services_Twilio_autoload', false);
```

This way the function will omit messsages when the handler is recalled. You can also check if the handler was created prior to redeclare it. I hope it works!

Check documentation online at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur when you include Twilio.php more than one. The solution in selected right answer will skip throwing error messages only. That will also stop throwing other errors.
Right solution-
Call the twilio.php with `require_once` function not with `require` everywhere. This will not include file again if already loaded.

```
require_once('twilio.php');
```